# How to display the name of sender instead of email address when sending email using google.appengine.api.mail.send_mail

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api

This is how I send email:

```
google.appengine.api.mail.send_mail(sender, to, subject, body, make_sync_call=MakeSyncCall, **kw)
```

source: [send mail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/mail#send_mail)

However, sender is always `sender = 'admin@xyz.com'`,
Therefore, when a receiver receives email, it will be like this:

[image]

I would like it shows the name of the person who sent email, for example: John Smith.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run some tests, and based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api#sending_mail_with_mailsend_mail), you just need to follow the same structure for the parameter `sender` as it is in the parameter `to`, as in the following example:

```
mail.send_mail(sender="Sender Jackson <admin@xyz.com>",
               to="Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>",
               subject="Your account has been approved",
               body="""Your email body""")
```

The receiver will in their in box an email sent by "Sender Jackson", instead of just the part preceding the`@`.